# How to prove the result of orbiting of a symmetric relation is also symmetric?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, symmetry

Suppose $R$ is a symmetric relation on a set $A$. I want to prove $R^n$(i.e $R\circ R\circ\dots\circ R$) is also symmetric. 
I approach the problem by considering first the odd numbers, for instance $n=3$.
$$R\circ R\circ R = R(R(R(x))) = R(R(y)) = R(x) = y$$
So $xRy$ analoge $yRx$. 
Then I consider the even numbers: $n=2$
$$R\circ R = R(R(x)) = R(y) = x $$
So I proved for even numbers that the orbiting results in reflexive relation.

How can I now prove the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume aRR...RRb.  Thus some u,v,... y,z with
aRu, uRv,... yRz, zRb.  By symmetry bRz, zRy,... vRu, uRa.
Consequently bRR...RRa, QED.

What does the functional notation R(x) mean?

Comment: i meant $xRy$ by $R(x)$. But thanks i totally got it.

Comment: That confusing notation, @SamFarjamirad, notation is not adequate to prove theorems about relations.  Note that i is the square root of -1.  Get used to it.